# Flink checkpoint fails randomly

Tags: kubernetes, apache-flink

I am running one Flink job in kubernetes. My setup is below

1. 1 Job Manager Pod
2. 4 Task Manager Pods
3. 3500 GB SSD hard disk shared thru NFS persistent volume claim between Job manager and Task manager pods for checkpointing, savepointing and RocksDB state backend
4. Using state.backend.rocksdb.localdir to flush rocksdb data to attched volume claim directory
5. Incremental checkpointing enabled

My flink job gets time series data (time, value) from kafka source, does aggregation and few other transformation and publish it to kafka sink.

Sometime my job fails with checkpoint exception(timed out in 10 minutes) mostly with one operator. I dont understand the meaning of Async duration (in image) and why is it taking the longest time. Before this exception, the throughput was very high 5-8 million records from kafka but after this checkpoint exception it gets very very slow. Another observation is increasing parallelism is not helping with increasing throughput. I enabled unaligned checkpointing also but its not helping much.

Flink Version: 1.13.2 Commit: 5f007ff @ 2021-07-23T04:35:55+02:00

Appreciate any help.

[image]

**Edit:**

After David's comment, I made following changes in my cluster

I added a separate node pool with 10 nodes and 1 local ssd (default size is 375 GB) attached to each node and scheduling my TM pods in this node pool. Also, I set the rocksdb localdir to spill states data to disk. I have 1 kafka source, can stream 1 billion timeseries data <time, value, key>. Here are the results :

Checkpoint interval = 15 minutes, enabled unaligned checkpointing also

1. First run, throughput was really high. It processed > 300 million data points in first ~40 minutes. Then third checkpoint failed with timeout. Throughput dropped after timeout
2. Cancelled first job and resubmitted job gain. Throughput is still very low, dropped from ~100 million / minute to ~1 million / minute.
3. Deleted flink cluster, recreated and resubmitted job again. It is running fine since last 18 hours, no checkpoint failure but throughput is really low. It processed only 625 millions yet.

Questions

1. Why throughput was really high with first run and then dropped?
2. Checkpoint failure still observed with first run?
3. Cancelling job with first run and resubmitting it didn't help to get same throughput?
4. Though job is running fine now with no checkpoint failure but why throughput is still low with all local ssd setup?
5. Why checkpoint size fluctuates so much? Sometimes it is more, sometime it is very less?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The first thing I would change about your setup would be to move the state.backend.rocksdb.localdir to ephemeral storage local to each TM pod. If the RocksDB local disk is actually an NFS mount, that's likely to cause problems.

As for the async duration, checkpointing is done in two phases. A (hopefully brief) synchronous phase during which stream processing is paused so that a few key things can be checkpointed, and then a typically much longer async phase during which the keyed state is checkpointed (in a separate thread from the ongoing stream processing).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I understand local ssd provides high IOPS and throughput but it has node affinity with nodes in k8s cluster. Lets say, I have 4 nodes of k8s cluster. I need to attach local ssd with each node so once my TM pod schedules to any node, it always gets some association with local ssd. Is it correct assumption? If this assumption is correct then is it ok if TM pod restarts and schedules to different node than earlier.

Comment: Another question, as local ssd storage is ephemeral, is it ok to loose state? What if this storage dies even before checkpointing? Sorry for lot of questions. Thanks in advance.

Comment: To get Flink performing well, you want your working state in the fastest available local storage -- either RAM or a local SSD. Flink is designed to not depend on the survival of the local, working state. Correctness after recovery only depends on checkpoints. If Flink does fail before completing the first checkpoint, then restart the job from the beginning.

Comment: David, I tried as per your inputs. Updated original question with my comments. Can you please help? Thank.

Answer (score 0):

Totally agreed with David, you should use local disks. There is no durability but performance requirement here. You can check this blog post [1] for details. As for the throughput drop, did you check the metrics of your local disk? are they burstable disks? You may have a bottleneck there. Check this blog post [2] to see whether it matches your case. If not disk, check also CPU & memory.

[1] https://flink.apache.org/2021/01/18/rocksdb.html

[2] https://www.ververica.com/blog/the-impact-of-disks-on-rocksdb-state-backend-in-flink-a-case-study

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have a use case where unaligned checkpoint is actually not helping at all but rather worsens it.

Unaligned checkpoint is meant for use cases where you experience sudden spikes or longer duration of backpressure - so instances where your throughput is very low to begin with.

Now unaligned checkpoint is persisting transient data in the checkpoint. That's why the size will blow up and actually can vary quite a lot depending on how much the network buffers are saturated.

Recovery from unaligned checkpoint also takes longer (more data to restore).

---

Now the question remains why there is a timeout with unaligned checkpoints. In theory that should only happen if your I/O is a bottleneck. Unaligned checkpoints blow up your checkpoint size from 1 GB to 9 GB from what I can see.

Another explanation may actually be a complete bottleneck on sink side; since you probably used `KafkaConsumer` and not the new `KafkaSource`, a minimum amount of data flow is required. But I'd kinda rule that out from your explanation.

To further investigate that, I'd need a screen shot of a timed out checkpoint (detailed statistics per task) and the logs.

---

Lastly there was a question about the overall throughput even with completely restarted job. This one is harder to answer with the information provided. I'd guess that you have some stateful operation where the heap statebackend just runs suboptimal after hitting a certain state size. You could try to tweak your statebackend. Make sure to tweak rocks DB for SSD for instance.